# NodeJs Buffer.toString() get different result in 7.x and 8.x version (module crypto)

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have a strange behavior using the module crypto from NodeJs.
I'm on windows 10, using nvm to manage different node version.

Here a sample to get the behavior:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let t1 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('abcdefghijklmnopqrs1@0', 'utf8').digest();
console.log(t1);
console.log(t1.toString('utf-8'));
```

When using node v7.7.3  i get the following output:

```
<Buffer ab 7e fe cb 51 e4 3b 3e 2c 53 94 86 bd 64 f0 4d e3 99 7c ff 98 d7 9a 38 8f ac 97 e2 c1 f0 94 0a>
�~��Q�;>,S���d�M��|��ך8�������
```

When using node v8.9.4 i get:

```
<Buffer ab 7e fe cb 51 e4 3b 3e 2c 53 94 86 bd 64 f0 4d e3 99 7c ff 98 d7 9a 38 8f ac 97 e2 c1 f0 94 0a>
�~��Q�;>,S���d�M�|��ך8������
```

You can see that the strings are different but the buffers are the same.

My use case is that i try to compare a saved string generated in 7.7.3 with the a new string generated in 8.9.4 and its not equal but it should be !
Can someone explain this to me, or give a workaround ?

Thanks,

Théo

Comment: Plz use the same string as a base to create the hash because i dont get the behavior with other string. I think this is something to do with number of byte but i'm not sure at all

Comment: I think that this is a problem in the different implementations of the `toString` method for the buffer with the `utf8` encoding. Try using the `toString('hex')` or `toString('base64')` encoding - the result is the same in both variants.

Comment: I've tried and as you said it works fine with 'hex' encoding, but i'm stuck with my utf8 string in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a more recent version gives a difference when converting to a utf8 string, you can use the custom function to convert from the [`feross/buffer`](https://github.com/feross/buffer/blob/master/index.js#L937) library:

```
// Copy from feross/buffer
function utf8Slice (buf, start, end) {
  ...
}

let crypto = require('crypto');
let t1 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('abcdefghijklmnopqrs1@0', 'utf8').digest();
console.log(t1);
console.log(utf8Slice(t1, 0, t1.length))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is good enough workaround for me. For others who might come by this problem, you'll have to copy two function from the feross/buffer library because "utf8Slice" use "decodeCodePointsArray"